# Website not displaying with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, firefox

I have written an HTML/CSS website that I have modified from a CSS Template site that I was given.

I have checked it against Chrome, Opera, Safari and it works fine.

The problem is that when it comes to firefox it only displays the logo and some very basic navigation stuff.

I was hoping someone with more web programming experience could take a look and let me know what might be going wrong.

I hate to ask such a general question but I really have no idea what is going on. You can find the website here: [matroscoe.ca](http://matroscoe.ca).

Thank you in advance for your help or pointers!

```
<?php require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en" id="index"> <![endif]-->

<head>
    <!-- Analytics -->
    <?php include_once( "php/analytics.php" ); ?>

    <base href="http://matroscoe.ca" /> 
    <title>Home \\ Mat Roscoe</title>

    <!-- SEO Information -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="This website provides current information on the research and work of Matthew Roscoe">
    <meta name="author" content="Matthew Roscoe, Graduate Student, http://matroscoe.ca">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">

    <!-- CSS Style Sheets -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<!-- Prompt IE 7 users to install Chrome Frame -->
<!--[if lt IE 8]><p class=chromeframe>Your browser is <em>ancient!</em> <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade to a different browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to experience this site.</p><![endif]-->

<div class="container">
    <script src="js/header.js" onload="header();"></script>

    <div class="home-page main">
       <section class="grid-wrap" >
          <header class="grid col-full">
            <hr>
            <p class="fleft">Home</p>
            <a href="about.php" class="arrow fright">more info</a>
        </header>

        <div class="grid col-one-half mq2-col-full">
            <h1>
                Robotics <br>
                A.I. <br>
                Computer Vision <br>
                Space Exploration
            </h1>

            <p align="justify">
                 I am a graduate student studying <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_computer_vision">3D Vision Systems</a>
                 and <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence">Artificial Intelligence</a> in robotic platforms. 
                 My goal is to work in space exploration robotics in the near future. 
            </p>
            <p align="justify">
                My current interests are focused around 3D object representation that has been afforded to us thanks to new RGB-D sensors. I am also investigating ways to learn about objects on the fly. 
                You can learn more about the project I am working on either through my <a href="#">Publications Page</a> or through my <a href="#"> Projects Page </a>. 
            </p>
        </div>


        <div class="slider grid col-one-half mq2-col-full">
            <div class="flexslider">
                <div class="slides">
                  <?php
                    global $post;
                    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
                    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <figure>
                            <?php $args = array(
                               'post_type' => 'attachment',
                               'numberposts' => -1,
                               'post_status' => null,
                               'post_parent' => $post->ID
                              );

                              $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                                 if ( $attachments ) 
                                 {
                                       //echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                                       $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachments[1]->ID, 'full' ); ?>
                                       <img class="front" src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="400px" height="370px">
                                 <?php } ?>
                            <figcaption> 
                            <div>
                                <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                <p class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>              </div>
                             </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div> <!--main-->
    <?php include("php/footer.php"); ?>
</div>

<!-- Javascript - jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
<script src="js/selectivizr.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var clicky_site_ids = clicky_site_ids || [];
clicky_site_ids.push(100591972);
(function() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;
  s.src = '//static.getclicky.com/js';
  ( document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ).appendChild( s );
})();
</script>
<noscript><p><img alt="Clicky" width="1" height="1" src="//in.getclicky.com/100591972ns.gif" /></p></noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems to load a totally different markup. Your head is empty and on the body there is only the header... can you please post the code of your first page please?

Comment: It seems that the page is never load, it's not a CSS problem. You should may post your PHP script.

Comment: I have updated the question so that it has the PHP for my index page.

Comment: It seems that there is a HTTP 403 error when you try to load `<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>`. Check the URL.

Comment: @pith I have tried fixing this and it has not seem to have helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with my site. The problem was that I was using Javascript in order to create the navigation menus and I had this tied into a faulty call to an onload() even that never actually happened. Once I changed form the Javascript to a much more concise PHP version the problem went away and I have no had any issues viewing the site using Firefox.

I want to post the answer separately from the others as it was different enough but if it were not for everyone looking at my code for me and making suggestions I never would have even caught the error. Thank you all for your assistance in getting me up and running on another browser!

Mat

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with your conditional comments for outputting the `<html>` tag. Firstly, they only seem to target Internet Explorer and I see no case where a `<html>` tag would be output for normal browsers. Secondly, the final conditional comment seems faulty:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en" id="index"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

should probably be

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en" id="index"> <![endif]-->
```

That said, I'm not sure why it is working in for example Chrome. I guess it may well be because of Chrome reacting differently to the broken conditional comment and applying the `<html>` tag within, while Firefox does not.

Also, try adding a final conditional comment simply looking like this:

```
<!--[if !IE]><html><![endif]-->
```

to target non-IE browsers and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this Peter. I have updated this in all of my files just incase. It however doesn't seem to have solved the not loading in Firefox problem. But again thank you for point this problem out to me.

Comment: agree with @PeterHerdenborg ,the missing <html> tag.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg I have tried adding in the tag that you suggested and it didn't help. Would it be better to remove the conditional tags all together?

Comment: @BadR0b1t apologies, I made a mistake when suggesting the final conditional comment. Could you try with the one in my edited answer now? If this doesn't help, then I guess it would be a good idea to get rid of the conditional comments completely and have a single, normal `<html>` tag.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg I went through and re-validated my HTML and that seems to have helped as most of the page is still showing up but not all of it but at least I am making progress. I also ended up removing all of the conditionals and using the normal HTML tag